# Graphite + Jenkins Job level Metrics

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, devops, influxdb, graphite

I am trying to get metrics for each individual job on Jenkins (I have 100 plus jobs).

Using InfluxDB i am able to get a lot of metrics (*eg: build number, build status message last successful build, project name etc.*) for every build in each job.

I am trying to get similar metrics using Graphite on Jenkins but I could not find a way to do this.

Plugins used on Jenkins:

1. https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/InfluxDB+Plugin
2. https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Metrics+Graphite+Plugin
3. https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Prometheus+Plugin

Any help is appreciated, thank you :)

Comment: Graphite data is mostly strictly time-series data, there is no metadata about logs, only a counter in a time-space.  It would be helpful if you linked the plugins or whatever you're using for each as well.  Sounds like ELK (Logstash) logging for it might be more what you want if InfluxDB isn't working for some reason (also curious why if InfluxDB has all that you're looking into graphite)

Comment: Hey. Sorry for the late reply. I have updated it.

InfluxDb works really well but i don't want to add another db to my current stack (which includes both graphite and prometheus) :p

@Thymine

Comment: Not sure if you're looking for a hosted solution, but we send Jenkins metrics to DataDog.  I have no idea on the cost (my company pays for it) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: It *could* be done, but appears it would require work that nobody has taken-on that I can find, and appears that generally that feature of graphite should not be used excessively because graphite doesn't appear to store it efficiently (although Jenkins usage seems like a very reasonable usage of it)

---

The code for the graphite plugin is pretty simple:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/metrics-graphite-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/jenkins/metrics/impl/graphite/PluginImpl.java#L69

Apparently graphite does support metadata as of version 0.9.9 (apparently 10/6/11)(I didn't fully realize that):
https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html

But those docs seem to imply its separate from the actual logged metrics, so looks like the plugin would need to make two requests to add that metadata.  One could add that into the plugin, but it would likely significantly slow down any log statement using that feature.

Also the [library it is using](https://github.com/dropwizard/metrics/tree/3748f09b249f47a24ef868595fed4556ec5e92b1/metrics-graphite/src/main/java/com/codahale/metrics/graphite) doesn't seem to support this metadata as far as I can tell, so adding that functionality would likely need to be done from scratch.

[Tags](https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tags.html) is another feature of graphite that seems to be quite rarely actually implemented in libaries/plugins, but that could be explored as well

Comment: Thanks for your extensive research. I went through all the links you provided and decided adding InfluxDB is much easier as it provides all the functionality out of the box. @Thymine